# When trying to register a user responding with "unauthorized"

Tags: javascript, back4app

### What is my Problem:

I'm making an vue3 app where the login and registration should be done over back4app.
So i initialize the connection as early as possible with the code below:

```
Parse.initialize(
  config.back4app_applicationId,
  config.back4app_clientKey
)
Parse.serverURL = config.back4app_url
```

After this code ran there is a successful health request to the back4app-Servers

And here is the code used for sign Up:

```
const parseUser = new Parse.User()
parseUser.set("username", userData.username)
parseUser.set("email", userData.email)
parseUser.set("password", userData.password)

try {
  await parseUser.signUp()
} catch (error) {
  console.error("error: ", error)
}
```

When the code runs the site is sending an request to the back4app server. Respon below 

Response-body:

```
unauthorized
```

Response-headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: DNT, Keep-Alive, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Content-Type, X-Application-ID, X-Access-Token, X-Parse-Master-Key, X-Parse-REST-API-Key, X-Parse-Javascript-Key, X-Parse-Application-Id, X-Parse-Client-Version, X-Parse-Session-Token, X-Requested-With, X-Parse-Revocable-Session, X-CSRF-Token, X-Apollo-Tracing, X-Parse-Client-Key, X-Parse-Installation-Id
access-control-allow-methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: https://localhost:3000
access-control-expose-headers: X-Parse-Job-Status-Id
access-control-max-age: 1728000
content-length: 24
date: Wed, 28 Jul 2021 10:23:10 GMT
server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
via: 1.1 7fcb41b117930690c299be9cec4a977a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: AX6MG8omTAxfGPQUHUR4SkRnWW9gp33_kqJHXgEFv9eIATnI1muxyA==
x-amz-cf-pop: FRA6-C1
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
x-powered-by: Express
```

### What have i tried:

- I tried to run the code on a different PC
- run the code on a site where the domain has a (not self-signed) HTTPS certificate
- giving parse the master key on initiation of my application
- different browsers
- searching for solution in back4app and parse docs
- Changing the public class level permissions for the Userclass

---

Hopefully i supplied all necessary information for the problem. I'm pretty lost what could be the error here and I'm very grateful for every answer.

Comment: Could you please try with the javascript key instead of the client key? You can find it in your App Settings -> Security & Keys.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Thanks a lot that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error was me using the clientkey instead of the javascriptkey.
Thanks to @DaviMacêdo for providing the answer.